# How to slow the speed using UIImage animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is the code what I'm using to animate an image. Don't matter the value set in the animationduration value, the animation always is running faster. I have this code after the Super ViewDidLoad area:

```
item1.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],nil];

[item1 setAnimationRepeatCount:1];

item1.animationDuration = 0.1;

[item1 startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think 0.1 is really short time to make this animation, try to set to 2.0. If the animation is a rotation, you can use this code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
[self.image setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(self.image.transform, M_PI_4)];
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
//Comment
}];
```

You can change the animation on M_PI_4 /4 or /3 or -1 set the value what you want. Hope this code helps. Thanks